# Launch Sketchfab iOS app from QR-Code to show AR model

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm trying to use the recently updated sketchfab app as an AR app for presentations https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sketchfab/id1201268000?mt=8.

In order to make this happen, my idea is to create an qr-code that launches the iOS app and passes the model-id as parameter.

Since the AR-Kit implementation in the sketchfab is pretty new, I cannot find any documentation for this.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks 
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I found the solution. It's pretty straightforward:

If you generate a URL-QR-Code like:

sketchfab://models/344eed672c4d4b8b9f6364bbf4684ccd

It automatically opens sketchfab and the app automatically opens the model